# How to make huge air bubbles in cake?

Tags: baking, cake

How can I adapt my cake recipe so that it will be elastic and have huge air bubbles inside of it when I take it out of the oven?

Comment: Very related information: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27855. Of course, this is for bread, but if you really go that route, you'll probably end up making something that most bakers from an anglo-saxon tradition would call a bread, not a cake, unless you prefer to make a soufflé instead of a bread.

Comment: @rumtscho what about without adding yeast? I think the flavour of yeast in a sweet cake would be unpleasant

Comment: If you don't want to use yeast, you don't have to use it, you can continue with chemical leaveners, that's what most cake recipes do. You'll just have a more cake-like texture, and won't be able to achieve the largest possible bubbles. It depends on what is more important to you, no yeast taste, or maximizing the bubbles.

Comment: Perhaps you could make blown sugar bubbles and fold them in *just* before baking - if the cake sets before they dissolve, that *might* work.